Software to texturize terrain model with images
I am trying to texturize a terrain model (Triangle Mesh) using images. I have the triangle mesh (in .dxf, .Landxml, .Obj formats), Images, Orthophoto, and lidar data. I tried Terraphoto (Terrasolid) and Blender software without success. Is there any straightforward software to do this?

Welcome Go_Ite!  Please edit your question and tags to reflect if you have any operating system and price preference (or gratis) for this software recommendation request.  Thanks, and again, welcome to our community!
